# Where can I get documentation on how to fetch data with Apollo and GraphQL?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've been able to create a GraphQL server that fetches data from a local MySQL database successfuly.
If I run a query in `localhost:4000/graphiql`, e.g.

```
{  
    allAuthors {
        id
        firstName
      }
    }
```

I get a correct output as below

```
{
  "data": {
    "allAuthors": [
      {
        "id": 24,
        "firstName": "Rosalee"
      },
      {
        "id": 83,
        "firstName": "Adeline"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to use the data on my React-Native e.g. fetch the first names and display them on the app. However I can't seem to find any useful documentation on how to use Apollo with React-Native. I can only seem to find for React and Apollo. Can someone help me get the documentation or useful tutorials on how to fetch data with Apollo and React-Native? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Documentation for apollo GraphQL, it's same for both react and react-native
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/

Comment: Will I be able to follow along with the react tutorial and apply it to the react-native?

Comment: Yes, both are react, just that native has native components instead of html